# Generate Asymmetric Triangular wave using Modulo function in single Line ? for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, math, graphics

y=abs(a-mod(x,(a+1)));

a=0 for sawtooth
a=1 for symmetric Triangle

https://flic.kr/p/oCJSHp

and I needed what function for following image using single line modulo function

https://flic.kr/p/oCJs9V

Comment: Please improve your question? I don't understand anything.

Comment: @viz Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [How to ask on stackoverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I know what a triangle wave is. But what do you mean with assymetric triangular wave? How should that look? COuld you post a picture or a link of the wave you want to generate?

Comment: I attach images links checkit out

Comment: @viz if you would like to ask a new or different question please post it as [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (instead of changing an old question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Matlab

(completely ignoring c/c++ tags)
Firstly the function is Piecewise so while it can be defined in a single line its much clearer  to break it then recombine...

### what you want it to do...

```
x=mod(x,1); 
if x <= 0.3
value = -1 / 0.3 * x + 1;  
else  %// x > 0.3
value = 1 / 0.7 * (x - 0.3);
end
```

### how to do it in one line...

to replicate the `if` operator within a single line can be done by logically testing for possible values, multiplying by the solution and summing all terms,

why?

The logical tests will return 0 if false and 1 if true so the unneeded solutions will be multiplied by 0 and the needed will be multiplied by 1.

so an (ugly) single line solution is:

```
(mod(x,1)<=0.3).*(1-1/0.3.*mod(x,1))+(0.3<mod(x,1)).*(1/0.7.*(mod(x,1)-0.3))
```

where

```
(mod(x,1)<=0.3)                                           %// first logical test

(mod(x,1)<=0.3).*(1-1/0.3.*mod(x,1))                      %// times value if true

(mod(x,1)<=0.3).*(1-1/0.3.*mod(x,1))+(0.3<mod(x,1))   %//plus second logical test

(mod(x,1)<=0.3).*(1-1/0.3.*mod(x,1))+(0.3<mod(x,1)).*(1/0.7.*(mod(x,1)-0.3))
                                                          %// times value if true
```

### results

```
x=0:0.1:3;
f=(mod(x,1)<=0.3).*(1-1/0.3.*mod(x,1))+(0.3<mod(x,1)).*(1/0.7.*(mod(x,1)-0.3));
plot(x,f)
```

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution, which works for `a_up=1`, `a_down=0` (first case saw-tooth), `a_up=1`, `a_down=1` (second case, triangle function) and any other combination (e.g. `a_up=0.7`, `a_down=0.3`, assymetric triangle wave)

```
t=0:0.001:10;
ampl=2;

a_up=0.7;
a_down=0.3;
if a_down==0
    y=mod(t*(ampl/a_up),ampl);
else
    t_1= 0:0.001:a_up;
    t_2= 0:0.001:a_down;
   helper= unique(mod(t_1*(ampl/a_up),ampl));
   helper2= ampl-unique(mod(t_2*(ampl/a_down),ampl));
   signal= [helper, helper2];
   signal2= repmat(signal,1,ceil(numel(t)/numel(signal)));
   y= signal2(1:numel(t));
end
figure(1)
plot(t,y)
```

What I do:

- `t` is my x-axis
- `ampl` my amplitude (the plot ranges from 0 to ampl)
- `a_up` the time interval which is needed to reach maximum
- `a_down` the time interval which is needed to reach zero again
- I made it case-sensitive because otherwise for `a_down=0` it would get wrong
- `t_1,t_2` are the time intervals which are needed for one slope.
- `helper,helper2` are the signals for rising or falling flank
- `signal` contains the combined signal
- `signal2` is periodically repeated, til it has the same or higher size than my x-axis(`t`)
- `y` is the reduced signal, so it has the same size as `t`